# URI path navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, file-uri

My jquery code is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
       // Computers runs windows
        $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
            this.href = this.href.replace("Volumes", "KP01DS0194TG");
        });
      }
      if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
        // computer is a Mac
        $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
            this.href = this.href.replace("KP01DS0194TG", "Volumes");
        });
      }
   });
```

My link in my html side of it is `<a href="file://///KP01DS0194TG/Quotes/Scanning/brother/Jobsheets/job no 12538.pdf">12538</a>`

however the Jquery doesnt work because of the `file://///` - if I take that out it works great, however I need it in there or else I can't connect to it - any ideas on what I can do to rectify this problem?

Comment: doesnt file only need 3 slashes? `file:///`

Comment: I'm not sure , Dreamweaver automatically did it for me

Just tried it with 3 slashed and it wouldn't connect to the file

Comment: Oh. do you plan on running this on a website? if so, ditch dreamweaver and google 'relative url paths'

Comment: Are you sure jquery is the issue? It's hard to imagine that jquery selectors care about the attributes actual value-tag relation when doing the search. Seems more like a browser safety feature.

Comment: It isn't a website per say , its just an internal website for the company - so the employee's can look at the files easier - its not for everyone to see

Comment: Im trying it on http://jsfiddle.net/syEPS/ so that I don't need to worry about any security issues or anything

Comment: I have tried this on google chrome on linux (without the os check ofc) and it works fine.

Comment: Ive tried loading up the link directly of a mac and it gives me an error - for it to connect to the server it has to be Volumes otherwise It wont find it

Comment: I think you will find that this is a browser security issue. Browsers will not allow an href to be written/rewritten with a file:// protocol. Similarly, window.location.href won't work either. The only way is to serve the page with the hrefs already adjusted - in other words, a server-side solution.

Comment: Exception is Google Chrome with (I think) <!doctype html>, hence (I suspect) d_inevitable's reported success.

Comment: how would I go about with setting up a side server? all computers will be using google chrome if thats any help

Comment: @chuck, sorry but without Dreamweaver or Chrome I'm not much use to you. Maybe d_inevitable can post his working javascript though I expect he did nothing more than removed the os check from your fiddle, as he reported. Significantly, the jsfiddle result frame is served with <!DOCTYPE html>. That's something you can try but (a) it's generally impractical (due to common headers and navigation) for one page of a site to have a different doctype from the others and (b) if you change doctype all through, then be sure to retest everything - layout and functionality.

Comment: Cheers Beetroot-Beetroot , Ill give that a go - hopefully @d_inevitable can share his javascript (: , but thanks everyone for your help , hopefully we can figure this out.

Comment: @chuck my js = your js minus the if statement that checks for windows or mac. Do you still want me to share it? It will not help you in your case. Sorry.

Comment: Well for anybody else to test: http://jsfiddle.net/syEPS/4/

Comment: Oh ok , thanks for that - however thats not helpful for my use , there are around 500 + users that will be using it , some with mac's some with PC's so it needs to be able to differentiate between the two - also it works with the file:/// - but as I said unfortunately It needs 5 slashes for it to connect to the server and open the file - thats my next problem \=

Comment: @chuck, I know its no use. And i have never meant it as a solution. This is just process of debugging it. Localizing the real issue. I don't think the jquery is the issue. Browser security is a candidate, but my browser doesn't reproduce it. So it may only not work for some browsers. Try using this http://jsfiddle.net/syEPS/5/ and monitor your console output. If you see the anchor links being logged inside the console, then it means its definitely not jquery's fault. You best bet is to use server-side scripts to adjust that path. Like php for example.

Comment: Oh no sorry - I wasn't having a go at you , I apologize if that's how it came across.
I'll give the php a go - and no doubt be back on stackoverflow for more help with it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "file" URL needs 3 slashes:

1) file://  # protocol

2) /some/path/myfile.pdf # file and path, including leading "/" for root directory

This is true whether the OS is Windows ("\" backslash) or *nix

ALSO:

3) Spaces are bad.  Consider naming your directories and files without spaces in them.

Otherwise, consider running "urlencode" on your path (which will convert spaces to "%20")

You might also be interested in the original RFC for URLs:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: Ive tried it with 3 slashes , it will not work - it only works with 5 (which dreamweaver automatically set up for me when linking to the files) if I do 3 , the JQuery will not recognize it and will not change it depending on the computer (it will with 2 - but not 3 or 5 ) , Ill change the spaces.